# Automate SVN authorization file modification

Tags: svn

In our project we have many SVN repository having its own authorization file(svn.auth) for access grant. Example of repository below:

//pers.svn.net/rep/rep1

```
 code
 svn.auth
```

//pers.svn.net/rep/rep2

```
code
svn.auth
```

We have around 20 repository, If we want to provide access to one user to all repository, then we have to manually modify svn.auth files at 20 place.

Is there any way to automate this manual process of granting authorization rights ?

Comment: If all the repositories are served from a common parent path, you can configure a single authz file and set up groups to simplify this greatly.

Comment: Thanks alroc, My all repository has separate root path having its own authz file. Thats why I am facing thsi multiple authz file update.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this:

- You can use LDAP or Active Directory authorization. This is nice because you're passing the responsibility to grant access onto some other sucker (Your system administrator). More time to play Candy Crush.
- When you specify your access file, simply share the same one via `AuthzSVNAccessFile`. Nothing says that the access file must be located in one particular place inside the repository, or that separate repos can't share the same one.
- If all of your repositories are under a single parent directory, configure them using `SvnParentPath`. Then, you only need a single httpd location configuration and a single auth file.

It's all in the [Subversion online book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic).